How to invert color shades of a map in OCR?

I have a US map with different shades of blue. (Source: CNBC Chart of the Day)
I am researching how to:

Count and correspond different shades of blue in the map (e.g., 1
for the lightest blue, 10 for the darkest if there are 10 shades of
blue).
Optional task: get the rgb code of each blue color.

The map is district court map of each state, so some states are further divided into several districts.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have not tried much yet but willing to try OCR coding in Python or R.

@KJ Hey I agree with you, and I think I was asking a wrong question. Can you please provide a way to do this on R as an answer? I would appreciate it and select the detailed answer for the community.

@KJ Ok, this is fine. Can you show me how to do this by using Shell trying irfanview? I did see your imgur image, but I am new to this. Would really appreciate your help. I basically need to categorize the distinct shades of blue into levels 1, 2, 3, et cetra from the lightest to the darkest. If you are answer is based on Shell, I will still choose it as it contributes to the stack overflow community and helps me tackle this issue.

@KJ Thank you so much for trying. This does seem to yield all unique colors with your last image attachment. Is my very best bet negating it to "eyeball" the distinct yellow shades? I am really stuck and I also understand and agree with the problem you shared if we go your route.

@KJ When you say "The more I try with blues the more I feel that out of context they have 0 value is it 30 states or 30 densities in legend", how do you mean by that? Are you getting all distinct blues for example in the north east map I uploaded?

@KJ I changed the picture to give the full background. So as you can see, in this example, the figure provides four distinc shades of blue. Now suppose we didn't know this. Would it be impossible to back out the exact four categories of blue just from the map itself using -irfanview-?

Already tried ImageMagick?
convert P6IT6.pdf -negate inv_P6IT6.pdf



Hi Jay, thanks a lot for the suggestion. Is there a way to score them from the lightest to the darkest? I am struggling to do this with my eyes even with the negation some yellow shades are hard to distinguish as “distinct”..

@FrankSwanton No clue, this is just something quick.
